Creating Topic Labels / Tags in Word Documents using R
I am creating content profiles consisting of a paragraph of text. At the bottom of each profile, I want to add tags or topic labels.
When assembled, the profiles will be an Office Word file, created in r using officer or a similar package.
The key objectives for the labels include:

a label may have one or more words
width is determined by the length of the label text
has a border with rounded ends
has background fill
is in line with adjacent labels
individual labels cannot wrap to a new line (i.e., labels may only have a height of one line)

The desired outcome looks like this.

This is relatively simple to achieve in HTML/CSS.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.rcorners1 {

  border-radius: 25px;
  border-width:1px;
  border-color: #A0A0A0;
  border-style: solid;
  background: #F0F0F0;
  color: #606060;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right:25px;
  display: inline-block;
 
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Content with Topic Lables</h1>

<p>This is a paragraph of text. It describes something, and that something is tagged with one or more topics. Those topics should appear as labels below. The labels will have rounded corners and be in line with one another. This works for HTML, but we want to generate the equivalent format in an MSWord document generated in `R` with the `officer` package or something similar.</p>
<p>
<span class="rcorners1">First Topic Label</span>
<span class="rcorners1">Second</span>
<span class="rcorners1">And Another</span>
</p>
</body>
</html>

I have not found a way to mimic the CSS approach in Word without using shapes for the label (as shown in the image).
I don't mind using shapes, but I don't see a way to add a shape using officer.
library(officer)

labels <- c("Label 1", "label 2", "label 3")

#create empty document
doc <- read_docx()

# add content to the document
doc %>%
  body_add_par("My paragraph description...") %>%
  body_add_??? # labels added here 

# Save the document
print(doc, target = "my_doc.docx")


I've tried using fpar (formatted paragraph), but, as a paragraph, it is not in line, so each label is a new line. There is also no means to round the corners.
ftext allows parts of a paragraph to be formatted, but it appears not to have border properties.
I tried experimenting with the rvg package to create a vector image of a rectangle with rounded corners.  But the dml generated with rvg only works for Powerpoint and Excel according to GitHub
I tried generating the labels as ggplot objects and inserting them as images. This was cumbersome, and I'm unsure how well that approach scales if hundreds of labels are used.
I've tried generating pure HTML/CSS and pasting that into Word, but the CSS formats are not compatible (i.e., there are no radiused corners, the fill does not fill the border on the text, etc.) so it does not appear as desired.
I attempted to isolate a shape from an existing Word document's document.xml (accessed by changing the file extension from .docx to .zip). My hope was to copy the XML, change the text, and change the width to match the text, then insert it using body_add_xml().  However, the shape's XML is very complicated and includes a unique o:gfxdata attribute value that is greater than 2500 characters; too long to post here unless requested.
This style of formatting seems very prominent in modern websites and other documents. There must be a way to implement this.
I am open to other packages.

EDIT
Here is a solution using ggplot.  The greatest challenge was adding the plots as inline objects as officer::body_add_gg() creates complete XML within a paragraph wrapper. The code below is pieced together from parts of the officer::body_add_gg officer::body_add_img functions.
library(officer)
library(magrittr)
library(rvg)
library(grid)
library(ggplot2)
library(ragg)

# Functions

make_label_gg <- function(l_text, unit_out = "in", 
                          label_size = 0.25, size_unit = "mm"){
  padding <- 0.3 #lines
  border_width <- convertHeight(unit(label_size, size_unit), unit_out, valueOnly = TRUE) # 0.1/2.54
  
  t_grob <- textGrob(l_text)
  t_width <- convertWidth(grobWidth(t_grob), unit_out, valueOnly = TRUE)
  t_height <- convertHeight(grobHeight(t_grob), unit_out, valueOnly = TRUE)
  l_width <- t_width + 2 * convertWidth(unit(padding, "lines"), unit_out, valueOnly = TRUE)
  l_height <- t_height + 2 * convertHeight(unit(padding, "lines"), unit_out, valueOnly = TRUE)
  
  radius <- l_height / 2 - border_width * 2
  
  r_plot <- ggplot() +
    annotate(geom = "label", x = 0.5, y = 0.5,
             label = l_text, label.r = unit(radius, unit_out),
             colour = "#808080", fill = "#F0F0F0",
             label.padding = unit(padding, "lines"),
             label.size = label_size, size.unit = size_unit) +
    theme_void() +
    theme(
      plot.margin = unit(c(0,0,0,0), "lines"),
      plot.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent", colour = NA),
      panel.border = element_blank(),
      panel.background = element_blank()
    )
  
  return(list(
    plot = r_plot,
    width = l_width,
    height = l_height
  ))
}

body_add_gg_labels <- function(x, l_text, style_id = "Normal", ...){
 
  label_list <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(l_text))
  res = 300
  scale = 1
  
  for(i in 1:length(l_text)){
    
    p <- make_label_gg(l_text[i])
    
    value = p$plot
    file <- tempfile(fileext = ".png")
    ragg::agg_png(filename = file, width = p$width, height = p$height, 
                  scaling = scale, units = "in", res = res, 
                  background = "transparent", ...)
    print(value)
    dev.off()
    on.exit(unlink(file))
    src <- file
    file_type <- gsub("(.*)(\\.[a-zA-Z0-0]+)$", "\\2", src)
    if (file_type %in% ".svg") {
      if (!requireNamespace("rsvg")) {
        stop("package 'rsvg' is required to convert svg file to rasters.")
      }
      file <- tempfile(fileext = ".png")
      rsvg::rsvg_png(src, file = file)
      src <- file
      file_type <- ".png"
    }
    new_src <- tempfile(fileext = file_type)
    file.copy(src, to = new_src)
    ext_img <- officer:::external_img(new_src, width = p$width, height = p$height)
    label_list[[i]] <- ext_img
  }
  
  run_str <- lapply(label_list, officer:::to_wml, add_ns = FALSE)
  run_str <- paste0(run_str, collapse = "") 
  # Wrap the concatenated runs in a single paragraph tag
  style_id <- NULL # or set your desired style_id
  open_tag <- officer:::wp_ns_yes
  ppr <- if (!is.null(style_id)) {
    paste0("<w:pPr><w:pStyle w:val=\"", style_id, "\"/></w:pPr>")
  } else {
    "<w:pPr/>"
  }
  xml_elt <- paste0(open_tag, ppr, run_str, "</w:p>")
  
  body_add_xml(x, str = xml_elt)

}

# Create the document
doc <- read_docx() # empty document
doc <- doc %>% 
  body_add_par("This is my paragraph...") %>% 
  body_add_gg_labels(c("hello", "goodbye")) # adds a paragraph with inline label images

print(doc, target = "my document.docx")


This still needs work to allow customization of font colours, size, etc., but it is a proof of concept, and it's the closest I've come to meeting my requirements and its "good enough".
This approach has limitations compared to a styled text approach. Namely, the labels are images. If you want to change the size of the labels or the font, you have to run the report again rather than changing a style setting.  If other post-report formatting or revisions were made, that can be time consuming. For that reason, I am not submitting this as an answer to my question, in case there is a better way to achieve the goal.

It could be helpful to provide an example of using ggplot and inserting since it doesn't seem like that should be cumbersome unless you mean that you're manually doing it rather than within R.

@socialscientist I was speaking in relative terms (matching fonts in the word doc, getting the image dimensions correct, etc. compared to applying a style to text), but inspired by your [correct] rejection of my statement, I am working towards a ggplot solution that addresses the "cumbersome" parts and will post progress soon.
